# Crash while destructing a static std::function in DLL used via C++/CLI

Tags: c++, visual-c++, c++-cli

Assuming I've the following code built as native DLL:

```
//// Header
#pragma once
#include <string>
#include <functional>

namespace native {

    typedef std::function<void(const std::string &line)> Log;
    __declspec(dllexport) void setLogHandler(Log fn);

}

//// Implementation
using namespace native;

static Log logImpl = nullptr;

void native::setLogHandler(Log fn) {
    logImpl = fn;
}
```

And I want to use this DLL in a .NET project like this (minimal code example):

```
//// Header
#pragma once

namespace Managed {
    public ref class Wrapper {

    public:
        delegate void LogHandler(System::String^ line);

        static void SetLogHandler(LogHandler^ fn);

        static void Nothing(System::String^ line) {};

    internal:
        static Wrapper::LogHandler^ logHandler = nullptr;
    };
}

//// Implementation
#include "CopylibCLR.h"
#include <copylib.h>
#include <msclr/marshal_cppstd.h>
#include <cstdlib>

using namespace Managed;
using msclr::interop::marshal_as;

static void logBridge(const std::string &line) {
    Wrapper::logHandler(marshal_as<System::String^>(line));
}

void Wrapper::SetLogHandler(LogHandler^ fn) {
    logHandler = fn;
    native::setLogHandler(&logBridge);
}

int main(int, char **) {
    Wrapper::SetLogHandler(gcnew Wrapper::LogHandler(Managed::Wrapper::Nothing));
    // WORKS if I uncomment the next line
    //native::setLogHandler(nullptr);
return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

(The code examples are enough to reproduce the crash.)

The application runs without error, but when the application terminates I observe a crash while the destruction of `std::function`:

```
KernelBase.dll!_RaiseException@16()  + 0x48 bytes   
clr.dll!COMPlusThrowBoot()  + 0x1a bytes    
clr.dll!_UMThunkStubRareDisableWorker@8()  + 0x25 bytes 
clr.dll!_UMThunkStubRareDisable()  + 0x9 bytes      Copylib.dll!std::_Func_class<void,std::basic_string<char,std::char_traits<char>,std::allocator<char> > const &>::_Tidy()  Line 449 + 0x33 bytes C++
Copylib.dll!std::function<void __cdecl(std::basic_string<char,std::char_traits<char>,std::allocator<char> > const &)>::~function<void __cdecl(std::basic_string<char,std::char_traits<char>,std::allocator<char> > const &)>()  Line 630    C++
Copylib.dll!`dynamic atexit destructor for 'logImpl''()  + 0xd bytes    C++
Copylib.dll!_CRT_INIT(void * hDllHandle, unsigned long dwReason, void * lpreserved)  Line 416   C
Copylib.dll!__DllMainCRTStartup(void * hDllHandle, unsigned long dwReason, void * lpreserved)  Line 522 + 0x11 bytes    C
Copylib.dll!_DllMainCRTStartup(void * hDllHandle, unsigned long dwReason, void * lpreserved)  Line 472 + 0x11 bytes C
ntdll.dll!_LdrxCallInitRoutine@16()  + 0x16 bytes   
ntdll.dll!LdrpCallInitRoutine()  + 0x43 bytes   
ntdll.dll!LdrShutdownProcess()  + 0x137 bytes   
ntdll.dll!RtlExitUserProcess()  + 0x63 bytes    
kernel32.dll!75db8287()     
mscoreei.dll!RuntimeDesc::ShutdownAllActiveRuntimes()  + 0x10e bytes    
mscoreei.dll!CLRRuntimeHostInternalImpl::ShutdownAllRuntimesThenExit()  + 0x13 bytes    
clr.dll!EEPolicy::ExitProcessViaShim()  + 0x65 bytes    
clr.dll!SafeExitProcess()  + 0x7d bytes 
clr.dll!HandleExitProcessHelper()  + 0x35 bytes 
clr.dll!EEPolicy::HandleExitProcess()  + 0x42 bytes 
clr.dll!__CorExeMainInternal@0()  + 0xf2 bytes  
clr.dll!__CorExeMain@0()  + 0x1c bytes  
mscoreei.dll!__CorExeMain@0()  + 0x71 bytes 
mscoree.dll!__CorExeMain_Exported@0()  + 0x8c bytes 
kernel32.dll!@BaseThreadInitThunk@12()  + 0xe bytes 
ntdll.dll!__RtlUserThreadStart()  + 0x24 bytes  
ntdll.dll!__RtlUserThreadStart@8()  + 0x1b bytes
```

I cannot explain why this code is crashing like this. Is my code wrong? Am I seeing "undefined behaviour" here?

Comment: Make sure both DLL and client code use the DLL version of runtime library. Using .NET complicates further.

Comment: Both projects are built using the Multithreaded Debug DLL `/MDd` Runtime.

Comment: It is a crash caused by heap corruption, pretty standard failure mode for native code.  Keep in mind that the code that crashes is never the code that caused the original corruption.  Having more than one CRT version in your process is always a good way to get this kind of mishap.

Comment: @HansPassant The code I posted is the only code required to reproduce the crash. I don't know where this code might create a heap corruption - no external libraries linked and both projects are in the same solution file. Both are being built using MSVC120 (2013); first one `/MDd`; second one `/MDd` and `/clr`. Are there other settings that might cause this type of issues?

Comment: Have you tried using an ordinary function pointer instead of std::function?

Comment: We have the same problem. The crash (BOOTUP_EXCEPTION_COMPLUS (0xC0020001)) is due to invoking managed code in shutdown code of your DLL (in DllMain) which is illegal. There the global static std::function is destructed.

We are still puzzled though how the managed code can end up in std::function; even #pragma unmanaged doesn't prevent the Interop of marshalling managed code inside a std::function.